# how to pass data from child to child component in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

`deals-transaction.component` is rendered by `app-transactions-details` and `deals-transaction.component` renders the `app-deals-approval component.`

How do I get the deals-transaction.component testPage() result or output and pass the data to `app-deals-approval` component and access the value on app-deals-approval component ngOnit ?

Is @Viewchild a good solution ? should it be pass as input ? . Thanks.

Thanks .

#deals-transaction.component html (this renders the app-deals-approval) I want to pass the data to app-deals-approval

```
  <div>
    <app-deals-approval > </app-deals-approval>
  </div>
```

#deals-transaction.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deals-transaction',
  templateUrl: './deals-transaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deals-transaction.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DealsTransactionComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(TableMultiSortComponent, { static: true }) tableMultiSortComponent: TableMultiSortComponent;
  transactionSubscripion: Subscription;
  tableOptions: any;
  @Input() transaction: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  accountId: any;
  dealDetails: any;

  constructor(
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
 
    private dealService: DealService,
 
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.leaseId = this.transaction.leaseId;
    this.propertyId = this.transaction.propertyId;   
    const actions = ["Copy", "Delete", "For Approval"];
    this.testPage();
  }
  private testPage() {
    this.searchInput = '';
    const status = 'ForApproval'
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService
      .getAllDeals(
        status,
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.table.pageIndex + 1,
        this.table.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.table.sortParams,
        this.table.sortDirs
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.testPageOutput = res.items;
      }, (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err)
    );
  }
```

#deals-approval.component.ts code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deals-approval',
  templateUrl: './deals-approval.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deals-approval.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DealsApprovalComponent implements OnInit {
  transactionSubscripion: Subscription;
  @ViewChild(TableMultiSortComponent, { static: true }) tableMultiSortComponent: TableMultiSortComponent;
  tableOptions: any;
  hasApproval = false;
  @Input() transaction: any;
  @Input() dataTest: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  DEAL_TYPES = DEAL.TYPES;
  totalDeals : number;

  dealType$: Observable<string> = new Observable<string>()
  firstSub: Subscription;
  accountId: any;
  data: any;
  searchInput: string;
  table: any;
  dealType: string;
  totalDealsForApproval = 0;
  constructor(
    private dealService: DealService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private trasactionService: TransactionService,
    private route: Router,
    private dealTransactionService: DealTransactionService
    
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
 
 }
```

Comment: Please read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: both are child components

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just add an `@Input() testPageOutput` to your `DealsApprovalComponent` and pass it in your template: `<app-deals-approval [testPageOutput]="testPageOutput"> </app-deals-approval>`

Comment: Are you trying to pass data from parent to child or from one sibling to another? Inheritance is important when data is not globally accessible.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I misread the question. In that case, you can either pass the data the parent of both and then pass the data to the other child. But you should probably pass the data to a service and use that for state management: Docs: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services
A guide: https://dev.to/avatsaev/simple-state-management-in-angular-with-only-services-and-rxjs-41p8

Comment: It's because the `testPageOutput` is set by an asynchronous task in `DealsTransactionComponent` - that's why it is not available in `ngOnInit()` of `DealsApprovalComponent`. Try to access it in `ngOnChanges()` instead of `ngOnInit()` of `DealsApprovalComponent`.

Comment: Thank you the help , appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `testPageOutput` is set by an asynchronous task in `DealsTransactionComponent` - that's why it is not available in `ngOnInit()` of `DealsApprovalComponent`. Try to access it in `ngOnChanges()` instead of `ngOnInit()` of `DealsApprovalComponent`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deals-transaction',
  templateUrl: './deals-transaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deals-transaction.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DealsTransactionComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  testPageOutput: any;

  constructor(
      private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
      private dealService: DealService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testPage();
  }

  private testPage() {
    this.dealService.getAllDeals(/*...*/)
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe(
         (res) => {
           this.testPageOutput = res.items;
         }, 
         (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err)
      );
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div>
  <app-deals-approval [testPageOutput]="testPageOutput"> 
  </app-deals-approval>
</div>
```

DealsApprovalComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deals-approval',
  templateUrl: './deals-approval.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deals-approval.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DealsApprovalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() testPageOutput: any;

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: any): void {
    if (changes.testPageOutput?.currentValue) {
      // do your stuff here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `deals-transaction.component`

```
<app-deals-approval [testPageOutput]="testPageOutput"> </app-deals-approval>
```

Inside `app-deals-approval component`

```
// use set since your `testPage()` is generating result in async
_testPageOutput: any;
@Input() set testPageOutput(value: any) {
    this._testPageOutput = value;
    // other operation you want to perform upon `testPageOutput` value changes
}
```

Comment: why is that the first value of _testPageOutput  become undefined and  then after 3 seconds it has now a value

Comment: and on ngOnit its still undefined

Comment: because your `this.testPageOutput` is not initialized to any default value in `DealsTransactionComponent`. so at first time it gets passed as `undefined` and when your `this.dealService.getAllDeals` gets response it sets `this.testPageOutput` in subscribe then value gets changed and again passed to `app-deals-approval`

Comment: question Sir, how do we avoid that it wont be undefined onNgONIT;'

Comment: Inside `DealsTransactionComponent` initialize `testPageOutput` with some default value, like if its object then `testPageOutput={}`, if string then `testPageOutput='defaultString'`. Set default value based on what type of data its going to hold at `this.dealService.getAllDeals`'s subscribe.

Comment: Thank you the help , appreciated.

Comment: Not a problem. Always happy to help, welcome